# Eclipse plug-in editor extension tab show “Generic” in “New” submenu

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am using "eclipse-rcp-helios-SR1-win32-x86_64"
64-bit eclipse running on JDK.

I am trying to add an action in my plugin via menu contribution.  When I add "org.eclipse.ui.menus," right-click on it then select "New," I only the "Generic" option.  I am expecting to see "menuContibution"

The issue is described in detail here, which also seems to include the solution: [link](http://samindaw.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/eclipse-plugin-editor-extension-tab-show-generic-in-new-submenu/)
From what I understand, the version of eclipse I have - helio SR1 - is an SDK version and should have the source included in the package.  I am not sure what I need to do to make those additional options show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have the "Generic" it means that you don't have the source plugins. But you have downloaded the right package (RCP one). I guess your download might be corrupted. Can you try downloading it again from a different mirror?

Comment: You were right. It must be something I've done along the way. I've downloaded a new instance(well, actually SR2 now) and it has the correct sub-menus. I'm not sure if I'm going to try to figure out what the source of the issue was. Maybe if I have some extra time later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i am try to this answer is useful.

> step-1: Eclipse menu bar Select **Help** menu
>
> step-2: select **Install New Software**

[image]

> step-3: **Eclipse project update link** (Required version) below image
>
> step-4: Choose **Eclipse plugin Development Tool** and
>
> step-5: After **Next** button click to finish.

[image: Eclipse RCP]

Eclipse can **Restart** after working successful.

Answer (score 1):

Installing **Eclipse plugin Development Tool**, as per Bharat Zala answer, is not enough. It still did not work for me:

[image: Eclipse PDE Extensions editor showing only 'generics' as the option]

I had to install **Eclipse SDK** and **Eclipse Platform SDK** packages:

[image: Selecting 'Eclipse SDK' and 'Eclipse Platform SDK' in 'Install New Software' dialog]

Then it finally worked:

[image: Eclipse PDE Extensions editor finally showing correct relevant options]

Note:
Lars Vogel in his book "Eclipse Rich Client Platform", in chapter 8 *Install Eclipse IDE for RCP development*, he advises for to 
*Download the Eclipse Software Development Kit (SDK)* as a recommended Eclipse edition for RCP/PDE development.

Most people probably have installed more mainstream Eclipse editions like *Eclipse for Java developers*. Installing *Eclipse SDK* and/or *Eclipse Platform SDK* as packages to them later should re-create SDK installation as advised by Lars.

Answer (score 0):

It did not work for me even after installing both.

I did go Update site "  http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5" and when it lists the different components.

Please unflag the "Group items by category" check box and Install "Eclipse RCP SDK" and related components.

Thant should fix the issue.

Thanks